# How can I stop react from making multiple network request simultaneously

Tags: reactjs

I am making a get request to get data from my rest API, and when I have the data react will keep on making the same request simultaneously multiple times.

this is the code:

```
export default function Transaction() {
  const [transactions, setTransaction] = useState([]); 
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) 
  const { id } = useParams();

  // this is where I am getting the problem
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTransc = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/get-records/${id}`);
      setTransaction(res.data)
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(res.data)
    };
    fetchTransc();
  },[id,transactions]);
```

Comment: In development, strict mode reinforces to render twice. This won't happen in production build. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the UseEffect hook is the dependency array. It tells react which variables to watch for changes. When a dependency changes or when the component is mounted for the first time, the code inside the hook is executed.

In your case the array indicates that each time “id” or “transations” change, the hook should be executed.
Since setTransation is called in the fetch function, that will trigger the hook again because “transations” is present in hook’s the dependency array.
Each time the transactions state variable is set with a brand a new object fetched from the url, react will trigger the useEffect hook.

If “transations” is removed from the hook’s dependency array, this should work fine. Maybe also adding an IF to check the “id” value could be useful to prevent errors.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchTransc = async () => {
    if(id != null) {
      const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/get-records/${id}`);
      setTransaction(res.data)
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(res.data)
    }
  };
  fetchTransc();
},[id]);
```

Comment: `id` would be `undefined` instead of `null` if there isn't one. I would use `if(!id)`.

Comment: @yousoumar the comparison using only **two** equal symbols makes `undefined == null` -> true. So in the example of this answer, if id is undefined or null is the same. The if statement `id != null` will be true if id is not null or id is not undefined (and will also be true even if id is 0 or any other value)

Comment: You are right Marisol. Sorry I forgot about that :)

Comment: @MarisolGutiérrez if I remove transaction in the dependency array it stops the error, but the problem is at the same time I am sending a post request that will add another transaction and without the transaction in the dependency array react will not automatically re-render the componenent that is why I can remove transaction in the array

Comment: @idrisadam please post a more complete version of the code so we can see whole the problem